# Trouble with Question 32b) Chapter 10 of Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

Question 32 of Chapter 10 from Spivak's *Calculus* has two parts:

> What is $f^{(k)}(x)$ if \begin{align} &\text{(a)} \quad f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-a)^n} \\ &\text{(b)} \quad f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2-1}\end{align}

A relevant lemma (proved in problem 30) is the following:

> If $f(x)=x^{(-n)}$ for some $n$ in $\mathbb N$, then $f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^k \frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}x^{-n-k}$

---

The solution manual answer to 32a) reads as:

> $$f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^k\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(k-1)!}(x-a)^{-n-k}$$

This is clearly a typo: "$(k-1)!$" in the denominator should, instead, be "$(n-1)!$"

Now, for 32b) the solution manual reads as follows:

> Since \begin{align}f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right), \end{align} we obtain, using part (a), \begin{align} f^{(k)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^k(n+k-1)!}{2(k-1)!}\left[(x-1)^{-n-k}-(x+1)^{-n-k}\right]\end{align}

Accounting for the typo that stems from 32a)'s solution, Spivak's final answer for 32b) is:

$$f^{(k)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^k(n+k-1)!}{2(n-1)!}\left[(x-1)^{-n-k}-(x+1)^{-n-k}\right]$$

After staring at this for a bit, I could not figure out where the $n$ was coming from. I assumed that maybe the prompt for 32b) contained a typo and should have, instead, been written as:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^n}$$

However, if this *was* what should have been written in the text book, then I am not certain how Spivak arrived at his proposed solution.

Consider the following:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^n}&=\\
&=\frac{1^n}{(x^2-1)^n}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)^n\\
&=\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\right]^n\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^n \quad (\dagger)
\end{align}

It's not immediately apparent to me how one arrives at $f^{(k)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^k(n+k-1)!}{2(n-1)!}\left[(x-1)^{-n-k}-(x+1)^{-n-k}\right]$ from the above expression $(\dagger)$.

Any clarifications would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't check coefficients, but, possibly, answer also should have power $n$ for subtraction.

Comment: @zkutch sorry, not sure I understand what you mean by "power $n$ for subtraction". Could you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry, not been clear. I mean $$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^n =\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\cdot \sum\limits_{i=0}^nC_n^i  \frac{d^k}{dx^k} \left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^i \left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^{n-i}$$ and after differentiation reunite back to some binomial formula.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the answer one good idea is to put $k=1$ in the answer and integrate to find the actual function  $f(x)$, which is not $\frac{1}{{(x^2-1)}^n}.$ To solve the 32b) problem you can use the "relevant lemma" and Leibniz Formula. It is not very clear what you want, I hope this will help.

Comment: My issue is that I do not believe the solution provided makes sense with respect to the prompt (also, integration has not been covered).

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is a typo but the fix is not the function $\frac{1}{{(x^2-1)}^n}.$ that is what I said in the answer.

Comment: ahhh, okay. I just wanted confirmation by someone more knowledgeable than me that, indeed, there is a typo. Thank you.